# Transferring Exactness

Tags: category-theory, modules, abelian-categories

If 
$$\begin{matrix}0&\rightarrow&A&\rightarrow&B&\rightarrow&C&\rightarrow&0\\
&&\downarrow&&\downarrow&&\downarrow\\
0&\rightarrow&D&\rightarrow&E&\rightarrow&F&\rightarrow&0\end{matrix}$$

is a commutative diagram with the top row being exact, then is the bottom also necessarily exact?

Comment: Edited. I'm assuming the downarrows are supposed to be in that diagram.

Comment: If the downarrows are isomorphisms this is an easy consequence of the five lemma. See:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_lemma

Comment: Of course one doesn't have to use the Five Lemma. If all vertical arrows are isomorphisms, exactness is transferred simply because this is obviously formulated in the language of categories and categorical properties are transferred by isomorphisms.

Answer (score 3):

No. If $A=B=C=0$, then the bottom row can be any sequence.

Comment: Or more generally, let the vertical arrows be zero.